# Using Group_Concat in getting events sessionwise

Tags: mysql, database

I have to get all the events for each session from db

```
id       Event       Session
1          A          Morning
2          B          Evening
3          C          Afternoon
4          D          Morning
```

How can I get result similar to this:

```
Result
Morning        Event1:A,Event2:D
Afternoon      Event1:C
Evening        Event1:B
```

Any help will be appreciated

---

Is there any chance to get the result as json?

e.g.

[{program:821, event:88, training:828, start:7:15 AM, end:7:50 AM, instructor:922, location:955, participant_id:451, session:447, day:445, intensity:••}]

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on scaisEdge answer. 
But this query would generate the result more like your expected result.

**Query**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

SELECT 
   `Session`
 , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('Event', id, ':', `Event`) ORDER BY id ASC) AS `events`
FROM 
 Table1
GROUP BY
 `Session`
```

**Result**

```
|   Session |            events |
|-----------|-------------------|
| Afternoon |          Event3:C |
|   Evening |          Event2:B |
|   Morning | Event1:A,Event4:D |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce8086/9

And if the ORDER is important you can use `ORDER BY FIELD()` to get the correct ORDER.

**Query**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

SELECT 
   `Session`
 , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('Event', id, ':', `Event`) ORDER BY id ASC) AS `events`
FROM 
 Table1
GROUP BY
 `Session`
ORDER BY FIELD(`Session`, 'Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening')
```

**Result**

```
|   Session |            events |
|-----------|-------------------|
|   Morning | Event1:A,Event4:D |
| Afternoon |          Event3:C |
|   Evening |          Event2:B |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce8086/12

Comment: is there any option to get the output as json... e.g. if i have more columns to be fetched and each record of events gets into a json

Comment: How should the json look like? @booota

Comment: [{program:821, event:88, training:828, tart:7:15 AM, end:7:50 AM, instructor:922, location:955, participant_id:451, session:447, day:445, intensity:••}]

Comment: group_concat output gets truncated after specific characters. How can we deal with this limitation keeping in mind that the output size is unknown

Comment: "[{program:821, event:88, training:828, tart:7:15 AM, end:7:50 AM, instructor:922, location:955, participant_id:451, session:447, day:445, intensity:••}] " the information is not within the example data you should ask a new question.with this information. @booota

Comment: "group_concat output gets truncated after specific characters. How can we deal with this limitation keeping in mind that the output size is unknown" use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;`

Answer (score 1):

You should use group by

```
  select session, group_concat(event)
  from my_table 
  group by Session
```